# PHP : Slim Combination of Optional and Required Param

Tags: php, slim-3

I want follwing type of route.

```
$app->get('/FetchImages/{catid}[/{subcatid}]/{page}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    //Code
});
```

In Route I want following:

- Category - Mandatory
- SubCategory - Optional
- Page - Mandatory

Can I do it in one route? If so, how can it be achieved? I want to have one function for these paths:

```
{catid}/{page}
{catid}/{subcatid}/{page}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have mandatory placeholders after optional. If you try, fastRoute (router, utilized by Slim) will give you an error.

And even if we abstract from Slim and fastRoute, I suggest you reconsider the URL structure of your API.
It is natural that mandatory comes first, optional comes later.

To be able to use same callback for the routes, I suggest you pass `page` as query parameter:

```
$this->get('/FetchImages/{categoryId}[/{subcategoryId}]', function($request, $response, $args) {

    $categoryId = $args['categoryId'];
    $subcategoryId = $args['subcategoryId'];

    //  Get requested page value.
    //  It defaults to null if no page specified
    $page = $request->getQueryParam('page', null);

});
```

And send request like this:

`GET http://myapp.com/FetchImages/kittens/dangerous?page=2`

In this case you're free to pass or skip page, and URL structure is still quite clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 routes with the same callback like this. It's not a perfect solution but you don't have to put the page inside a query parameter.

```
$myCallback = function($request, $response, $args) {
    $catid    = $args['catid'];
    $subcatid = isset($args['subcatid']) ? $args['subcatid'] : null;
    $page     = $args['page'];
    // do other stuff
};

$app->get('/FetchImages/{catid}/{page}', $myCallback);
$app->get('/FetchImages/{catid}/{subcatid}/{page}', $myCallback);
```

Comment: So which is better solution? Because i think sending query param is safe and no problem in it. But i want to know proper way to do this task.

Comment: I would say there are both good. But they have a different outcome. You can either choose this version if you want to have `page` as path-parameter or the other one if you want page as query-parameter.